# C# and ISO 8583 - 1987

Tags: c#, iso8583

Hi I have to write out a project that will use the ISO 8583 standards that should be written to a Message Queue. I have read up on ISO 8583 and i have a understanding on the format for this standard. My problem is how to setup a ISO 8583 message to put on a Message Queue (I know how to use the message queue which is not the problem). Maybe some guidance or some basic code to get me started (I dont expect a full project to be posted to help me) or maybe some reading material to guide me to convert this ISO 8583 standard into code.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100084/Introduction-to-ISO-8583 I found it helpful when I had to consume ISO 8583 messages

Comment: Yes i did read it earlier, gave me a better understanding on the standard. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure about the message queue but maybe you could use [OpenIso8583.Net](http://code.google.com/p/openiso8583net/) to format the messages to the ISO 8583 standard?

Comment: I think this will help me. Thanks for the help.